# How to convert audio.m4a to audio.amr on OS X?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, amr

I tried installing ffmpeg

```
$ brew install ffmpeg
```

and running ffmpeg

```
$ ffmpeg -i audio.m4a -ar 8000 -ab 12.2k audio.amr
```

I got the following error:

> Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default
>   encoder for format amr (codec amr_nb) is probably disabled. Please
>   choose an encoder manually. Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0

I can't figure out how to enable amr_nb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Step 1: Find the AMR install option for ffmpeg Homebrew package

List all install options for ffmpeg Homebrew package:

```
$ brew info ffmpeg
```

> ffmpeg: stable 3.2.2 (bottled), HEAD 
>   Play, record, convert, and stream audio and video 
>   https://ffmpeg.org/ 
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.2 (239 files, 50.3M) * 
>   Built from source on 2016-12-14 at 17:43:58 with: --with-opencore-amr 
>   From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/ffmpeg.rb
>
> ==> Dependencies 
>   Build: pkg-config ✔, texi2html ✔, yasm ✔ 
>   Recommended: lame ✔, x264 ✔, xvid ✔ 
>   Optional: chromaprint ✘, fdk-aac ✘, fontconfig ✘, freetype ✘, frei0r ✘, game-music-emu ✘, libass ✘, libbluray ✘, libbs2b ✘, libcaca ✘, libebur128 ✘, libgsm ✘, libmodplug ✘, libsoxr ✘, libssh ✘, libvidstab ✘, libvorbis ✘, libvpx ✘, opencore-amr ✔, openh264 ✘, openjpeg ✘, openssl ✘, opus ✘, rtmpdump ✘, rubberband ✘, schroedinger ✘, sdl2 ✘, snappy ✘, speex ✘, tesseract ✘, theora ✘, two-lame ✘, wavpack ✘, webp ✘, x265 ✘, xz ✘, zeromq ✘, zimg ✘
>
> ==> Options 
>   ... 
>   --with-opencore-amr 
>           Enable Opencore AMR NR/WB audio format 
>   ...

More concisely:

```
$ brew info ffmpeg | grep amr
```

> --with-opencore-amr

### Step 2: Install ffmpeg using Homebrew install options

```
$ brew install ffmpeg --with-opencore-amr
```

### Step 3: Run ffmpeg

```
$ ffmpeg -i audio.m4a -ar 8000 -ab 12.2k audio.amr
```

Comment: Love you! Save my life!

Answer (score 0):

AMR codec support is via external libraries.

You can get OS X binaries with those libraries linked from https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/. Get the snapshot or nightly build.